# Is there a library that will detect the source code language of a block of code?

Tags: python

Writing a python script and it needs to find out what language a block of code is written in. **I could easily write this myself, but I'd like to know if a solution already exists.**

Pygments is insufficient and unreliable.

Answer (score 13):

[Pygments](http://pygments.org) can guess too. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
>>> from pygments.lexers import guess_lexer, guess_lexer_for_filename

>>> guess_lexer('#!/usr/bin/python\nprint "Hello World!"')
<pygments.lexers.PythonLexer>

>>> guess_lexer_for_filename('test.py', 'print "Hello World!"')
<pygments.lexers.PythonLexer>
```

Comment: it says `<pygments.lexers.NumPyLexer>`

Comment: Awesome. if you call name on a returned object it'll return you a language name.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you should try what this very site uses: [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235982/how-code-color-is-set-in-stackoverflow))

[EDIT]J.F. Sebastian pointed me to [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325165/is-there-a-library-that-will-detect-the-source-code-language-of-a-block-of-code#325521))

Comment: may i mention this site is terrible at doing this? (at least in my opinion)

Comment: A little is better than nothing. MarkDown is OSS, so he can fix anything he needs.

Comment: Markdown does no syntax colouring at all, it just turns *blah* into <b></b> tags and other such formatting. The syntax highlighting is done by google-code-pretty (in javascript). I added it to your answer, hope you don't mind..

Comment: So "all" he has to do is convert the Javascript (the library) to Python (what he uses)...

Comment: What better solution is there when there is no existing Python library?

Comment: @Aaron: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325165/is-there-a-library-that-will-detect-the-source-code-language-of-a-block-of-code#325521

Answer (score 3):

Vim uses a bunch of interesting tests and regular expressions to look for certain file formats. You can look at the vim instruction file at `vim/vim71/filetype.vim`, or [here online](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/filetype.vim).

Answer (score 3):

This can be a little difficult to do reliably. For example, what language is the following:

```
print("blah");
```

The most reliable way (aside from having the user select the correct language, of course) is to check if the first line is starts with `#!` ("hashbang") - whatever is after this is the intepreter for the scripting language.

That will work reliably for a lot of scripting languages (including python, shell scripting, perl, ruby etc etc..), but not for compiled languages..

You could look for unique syntax stylings, or specific keywords and weight each one towards a specific language. For example `$#somevar` is probably Perl. `somevar.each do |another| ..... end` is probably ruby.. but this would end up being a *lot* of work, and will not always work (especially with short code blocks)

The other obvious way is to use the file-extension. If it's `*.pl` it's probably Perl code..

What are you trying to achieve? If you want to syntax highlight, look at what [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) does - basically a reasonably intelligent, generic syntax highlighter..

In the above above ambiguous example, `print` is probably a statement or function name, `"blah"` is probably a string. If you highlight those two differently, you've successfully highlighted a *lot* of different languages, without having to detect what one it actually is.. but that may not always work, depending on the task..

Answer (score 3):

Ohcount has been developed for this exactly:
http://labs.ohloh.net/ohcount

They are using it at www.ohloh.net to count the contribution of people in languages.

The bad news is that it is coded in ruby, but I am sure that you can integrate it one way or the other in python.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked this question, GitHub have released the code they use to detect programming languages, [**Linguist**](https://github.com/github/linguist/). In my experience, GitHub is very accurate.

> #### Language detection
>
> Linguist defines the list of all languages known to GitHub in a yaml file. In order for a file to be highlighted, a language and lexer must be defined there.
>
> Most languages are detected by their file extension. This is the fastest and most common situation.
>
> For disambiguating between files with common extensions, we use a bayesian classifier. For an example, this helps us tell the difference between .h files which could be either C, C++, or Obj-C.

Ruby gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/github-linguist

If you can't use Ruby for whatever reason, the logic is simple enough to port https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/language.rb

Answer (score 1):

> what language a block of code is written in

What are your alternatives, among what languages? There is no way to determine this universally. But if you narrow your focus there is probably a tool somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can check highlight.js which automatically highlights the code block, they say they are using some kind of heuristic methods to accomplish this http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

Answer (score 0):

As other have said Pygments will be your best bet.